# Issue with decimals and how they're represented in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, postgresql, math

I am trying to add a Price column to my ASP.NET Crud, and it works.
The only issue I am having is that it is taking the wrong input.
I am a beginner so I must be overlooking something, but anyways, I insert a value like 15.50 and it becomes 1.550

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63QHh.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISQ9T.png)

Here are some snippets of the code, I don't know what I messed up here.
namespace CRUDNet.Models

```
{
    [Table("Produtos")]
    public class Produto
    {
        [Column("ID")]
        [Display(Name = "ID")]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Column("Nome")]
        [Display(Name = "Nome")]
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        [Column("Valor")]
        [Display(Name = "Valor")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
        public decimal Valor { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I was expecting that when I insert a value like 15.50 I get 15.50 and not 1.550

Comment: You have a number format {0:C}  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#use-standard-numeric-format-strings and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the--custom-specifier-1

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your local decimal and the group separators are not what you think they are where the grouping separator is a period (`.`) and is being ignored as it's not relevant to parsing the number.

```
    var s = "15.50";

    // en-gb uses a period/full stop as the decimal separator.
    var periodCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-gb");
    Console.WriteLine($"{Decimal.Parse(s, periodCulture):N}");
    // 15.50

    // Using de-de as it use a comma as the decimal separator.
    var commaCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-de");
    Console.WriteLine($"{ Decimal.Parse(s, commaCulture):N}");
    // 1,550.00
```

My current culture is en-gb which uses the period as the decimal separator and the comma as the grouping separator.

Answer (score 1):

Format: {0:D} Displays integer values in decimal format. You can specify the number of digits. (Although the type is referred to as "decimal", the numbers are formatted as integers.)

for 2 places use it like
DataFormatString = {0:n2}

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem with your 15.50 turning into 1.550 in your application is related to how the Valor field in your Produto class is being formatted and possibly how the culture settings of your application are interpreting decimal numbers.

In your code, the [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")] is set to format the Valor as currency, and this can vary based on the application's culture settings. If your application is using a culture where a comma is a decimal separator, it could display 15.50 as 1.550.

1- Check the Culture:
1-1 Setting the Desired Culture: you can do so in your application's startup code or controller actions.
ex:

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

2- Change the Format String: Try changing the DataFormatString to something like "{0:0.00}" to get a more consistent format.
3- Review How Input is Handled: Make sure the input 15.50 is being correctly parsed as a decimal in your code.

4- Debugging Tip: Try removing the [DisplayFormat] attribute temporarily to see the raw value of Valor, helping you determine if the issue is with storage or display of the value.

Comment: @thux Can you send me the result please?